# "Paradox" low power implications?

Tags: chi-squared-test, statistical-power

I hit the following problem: I calculated the p-value of a chi-square test, which gave me a result near 1 and clearly does not lead to rejection. On the other hand, I determined the power of the same test as 6%, which means a type II error
of 94%. This situation would imply non-rejection as decision, which is wrong with a high probability, but still we should not reject because of the p-value. Is this a paradox resulting from low-power tests or is it some misunderstanding of the underlying conditional probabilities? If it is a "paradox", could I interpret it as: if there is no rejection and low power, we are even less able to say anything 
about "H_o holds" or "H_a" holds than in a situation of no rejection and high power?

Comment: What's that detail df=NA in your output? Shouldn't 0.25,0.25,0.3,0.11 sum to 1? Chi-square statistic should be 10 times bigger if you multiply sample frequencies by 10, not (about) the same. Please make your observed and expected frequencies visible.

Comment: Sorry, there is a bug in parts of my question. The sample size n=2600-situation leads to a very small p-value, thus rejection, thus the potential "paradox" only applies to the n=260-situation. But still I would be interested in opinions to my interpretation of "such low power does not yield any statement for the situation n=260". Best regards, Statos

Comment: Please fix the question, rather than giving an answer that isn't an answer. Role reversal is a good idea here: in reading other threads, you want to read first the question, then the answers. You don't want to find that the question posted wasn't even what the poster really wants to know.

Comment: As is, your code produces errors. As @NickCox pointed out, the pvalues must sum to 1. Also, the two + signs cause problems.

Comment: Statos, you appear to have multiple accounts with SE. Please merge them so that you can edit and comment on your own question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts.

Comment: Fixed the question. It focuses only on the seeming "paradox". Which is no paradox, as I learned by denoting the conditional probability P(reject H_o | H_o false). - Statos

Comment: Keep in mind that failure to reject the null hypothesis *should not* be interpreted as evidence in favor of it.

Comment: And besides the ok P(reject H_o | H_o false) I denote P(reject H_0 | H_0 true). As from Marc Claesen's comment and from Peter Flom's answer follows, we do actually *not* talk about probabilities of hypotheses. This was my main confusion.

Comment: Questions raised yesterday about likely mistakes in your calculations have not been addressed.

Comment: There was a bug in my calculation, the corrected chi-square-calculation can be found in http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67457/df-missing-in-r-output-of-chi-square-test
and leads to reject H_0, which only leaves my more theoretical question on H_0, power and type 2 error at this place.
Multiplying the x in the correct calculation by 10 would also result in a ten-fold chi-square:
x<-c(0.16*260,0.48*260,0.31*260,0.05*260,0)
chisq.test(x, p=c(0.25,0.25,0.3,0.11,0.09),simulate.p.value = TRUE, B = 1000) yields chi-square=95.4358 - the same chisq.test with 10*x yields chi-squared = 954.3576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the site. You seem to have a few things confused.

Low power means that you could make a type II error. A type II error is failing to reject the null when it is, in fact, false. You can only make a type II error when you a) Fail to reject the null and b) Are incorrect. So, it's not that there is a 94% chance that your failure to reject is incorrect; it's a 94% chance IF the right decision was to reject. What if the decision is correct? Then it's no error at all.

Next, you have a $\chi ^2$ value of 0.25. The expected value of $\chi ^2$ under the null is the df. Your value is less than the df, it won't be significant. In fact, your data is less associated than random data would be.

Comment: Peter, I edited the answer cancelling the chi-squared part, as I shortened the question.

Comment: I've objected to this edit. Your question has changed quite radically; it would be much simpler to ask a new question. You did accept this answer.

Comment: A great ressource on my problem is Haller's and Krauss' paper on misinterpretations of significance: http://www.metheval.uni-jena.de/lehre/0405-ws/evaluationuebung/haller.pdf