# df missing in R output of chi-square- test?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

I performed a chi-square goodness-of-fit test with R, which uses simulation of the p-value:

```
x<-c(0.16*260,0.48*260,0.31*260,0.05*260,0)

chisq.test(x, p=c(0.25,0.25,0.3,0.11,0.09),simulate.p.value = TRUE, B = 1000)
```

The output says:

```
Chi-squared test for given probabilities with simulated p-value (based
    on 1000 replicates)

data:  x
X-squared = 95.4358, df = NA, p-value = 0.000999
```

I think the df should be 4. Why is it missing in the output? The documentation at

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/chisq.test.html

does not mention the df-related output.

Any similar experience with R packages? Would you consider it worth a feature request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've specified `simulate.p.value = TRUE`, so `chisq.test` will use a test statistic and P-value based on a Monte Carlo approach. In this case, there is no assumed chi-square distribution for the test statistic, so there is also no df parameter involved.

Comment: Hong Ooi answered the main question and deserves the acceptance in my view. My answer was secondary.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation says "The entries of `x` must be non-negative integers". That's not true in your case, yet the function doesn't throw you out. But there's still a question of whether what you are doing is non-standard in some sense, which might contribute to your difficulties in other problems.

```
> x<-c(0.16*260,0.48*260,0.31*260,0.05*260,0)
> x
[1]  41.6 124.8  80.6  13.0   0.0
> chisq.test(x, p=c(0.25,0.25,0.3,0.11,0.09))

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  x
X-squared = 95.4358, df = 4, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: A rounded x<-c(42,125,81,13,0)
    
    Chi-squared test for given probabilities with simulated p-value (based on 1000 replicates)

results in
X-squared = 95.1776, df = NA, p-value = 0.000999

Comment: You are not addressing my main point. It doesn't seem to matter _here_, but why don't you have observed frequencies as integers? (Your rounding changes the total to 261.)

Comment: I took the percentages from a paper - a survey on facebook and privacy, see https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~smb/papers/a9_Johnson.pdf) and knew the sample size was n=260. However, I guess the authors have rounded the percentages presented in table 2 - thus my back-calculation yields non-integers. Nevertheless, I wanted understand, if chi-square can tell us non-representativeness here.

Comment: I see. Chi-square tests a null hypothesis. What you mean by non-representativeness is not clear to me. Chi-square can't check sampling design, if that is what you mean.

Comment: It cannot check sample design, but it can , reject the null hypothesis "sample and population have the same distribution of percentages",right?

Comment: That's composition, not design. The point is that the test cannot know how the data were produced, only what they are.